# Scripts added in the head miscelleneous script section from admin rendering in body tag instead of head tag

Tags: magento2, header

I have added a GTM code into the head section of my website from Admin -> Content -> Design -> Configuration -> HTML Head -> Script and stylesheet like below

```
<!-- GTM tag start -->
<script></script>
<!-- GTM tag end -->
```

But only the comments before and after the script tag is coming with in the head section and the script content is coming in the body.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below setting in Magento admin:
[image]

And if its enable then disable it and run the deploy command.